# Using both text and argument in same function in R

Tags: r, parsing, text, formula, eval

First of all need to create the same data;

```
library(tibbletime)
date <- seq(from = as.Date("1979-09-01"), to = as.Date("2019-12-01"), by = "month")
n <- length(date)
df <- matrix(NA, n, 2)
df <- data.frame(df)
var <- sample(1000:5000, n)
df[1] <- date
df[2] <- var
names(df) <- c("date", "var")
df <- as_tbl_time(df, index = date)
```

How can i use command below;

```
filter_time(df, ~"1979-09")
```

by paste0, eval(parse(text = "") I tried that one;

```
filter_time(eval(parse(text = paste0("df",",", "~" , "1979-09",sep = ""))))
```

but it didn't work. I have problem with time object which must be as text format. If that code works, it is possible to use in for loop, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish this with `as.formula()`

```
filter_time(df, as.formula(paste0("~", '"', year, '"')))
```

Full reprex:

```
library(tibbletime)

date <- seq(from = as.Date("1979-09-01"), to = as.Date("2019-12-01"), by = "month")
n <- length(date)
df <- matrix(NA, n, 2)
df <- data.frame(df)
var <- sample(1000:5000, n)
df[1] <- date
df[2] <- var
names(df) <- c("date", "var")
df <- as_tbl_time(df, index = date)

year <- paste("1979-09")
paste0("~", '"', year, '"')
#> [1] "~\"1979-09\""

as.formula(paste0("~", '"', year, '"'))
#> ~"1979-09"

filter_time(df, as.formula(paste0("~", '"', year, '"')))
#> # A time tibble: 1 x 2
#> # Index: date
#>   date         var
#>   <date>     <int>
#> 1 1979-09-01  3600
```

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

We could use `reformulate` to construct the expression

```
library(tibbletime)
filter_time(df, reformulate(termlabels = dQuote("1979-09", FALSE)))
```

-output

```
# A time tibble: 1 × 2
# Index: date
  date         var
  <date>     <int>
1 1979-09-01  1700
```

Comment: It worked :) Thanks a lot. I will be using this for academic paper analysis. Special thanks.